# How to show multiple images in a single page of LeavesViewController?

Tags: ios, ios4, page-flipping

The classes provided by Leaves developed by Tom Brow supports single images for each page of the book with flip effect. In one of our projects we need to show multiple images in a single page along with the flip effect. Has anybody done that with 'Leaves' or is there any other alternative?

We need this images to be added separately so that we can use UIImage selected actions as this  images are also required to replaced.This view will also have UITextBox and UILabel.

I know that from iOS 5 on wards UIPageViewController is available which can serve this purpose but for this project we need to support iOS4 also so UIPageViewController can be ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to render two images in a graphics context and then extract the image from the context and draw it in pdfcontext. Hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but we need each of this image to be select-able so that it can be replaced so combining two images to a single one is also not an option.